# PrimeFaces components are not rendered on a page

Tags: maven, jsf-2, primefaces

PrimeFaces components don't show up. I read all the answers, but could not find her decision situation.
In Maven add:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.13</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
   <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In web.xml add:

```
    <!-- Staring JSF -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- JSF URL mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And file with primefaces components:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <h:head>
      <title>SocialMap</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
     <p:button value="spend"/>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Please help solve this mistake

Comment: what if you do a 'view-source' of the page?

Comment: View page source:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"><head id="j_idt2">
    <title>SocialMap</title></head><body>
    <p:button value="asfs"></p:button></body>
</html>

Comment: No, it don't work for me...

Comment: Thank you )) then as I added primefaces-6.0.jar in WEB-INF/lib everything work. But why it's don't work with dependency maven ?